# Solving integral by partial integration

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Looking at the integral

$$\int\limits_1^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} \ dx $$

Is it ok to write

$$\int\limits_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \ dx = \left[-\frac{\cos(x)}{\displaystyle x}\right]_1^{\infty} + \int\limits_1^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos(x)}{x^2} \ dx$$

and then saying that the existence is given since $ \left|\ \dfrac{\cos(x)}{x^2} \right|\ \leq \dfrac{1}{x^2}$

I've seen a proof on the existence of the above integral which is much more complicated than this, so I'm not sure if this can be correct.

Comment: How do you plan on accounting for the first term after using IBP?

Comment: What does IBP mean?

Comment: Integration by parts

Comment: I mean the $\frac{\cos x}{x}$ term you have from 1 to $\infty$

Comment: for infinity, the term vanishes, right?

Comment: [$\large -\operatorname{si}\left(1\right) \approx 0.6247$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2.E10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_1^{\infty } \frac{\sin (x)}{x} \, dx= \tag 1$$
$$=\left[\frac{-\cos x}{x}\right]_1^\infty-\int_1^{\infty } \frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,dx$$
$$\left[\frac{-\cos x}{x}\right]_1^\infty=\underset{x\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(-\frac{\cos x}{x}\right)+\frac{\cos 1}{1}=0+\cos 1=\cos 1$$
$$\int_1^{\infty } \frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,dx\le\int_1^{\infty } \frac{dx}{x^2}$$
Last integral converges, therefore the first integral $(1)$ converges